# Algorithms: How do I sum O(n) and O(mlog(n)) together?

Tags: algorithms, big-o, algorithm-analysis, runtime

I'm doing a running time analysis using the aggregate method and I'm a bit confused about what would be the result in this case. I have some intuition in inferring that it would be O(mlog(n)) but I'm not sure

Comment: Do you know that `O(n)` and `O(m logn(n))` are using the same `n`?  If not then you have to rename one of the `n` variables, For example `O(k)` and `O(m log(n))` can become `O(k+ m log(n))`  It could also be that the `n` in the first formula is ``m` in the second — we're not given context to know one way or the other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *can* have `+` in big-o, when you have terms with different parameters.

`O(n + mlog(n))` describes the general case where n and m are different terms, that grow independantly.

In the case where n is fixed, that is equivalent to `O(m)`. In the case where m is fixed, that is equivalent to `O(n)`. In the case where n is proportional to m, it is `O(nlog(n))`